# How to scope a ValidationGroup

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, validation, validationgroup

I have 2 buttons, `costButton` and `detailsButton`, and one textbox (with associated `RequiredFieldValidator`) on my aspx page. `costButton` button and the textbox belong to ValidationGroup `costValGroup`.

`detailsButton` doesnt belong to any validation group. When it is clicked, it triggers the validators in `costValGroup`, **which I want to avoid**.

Here's the client-side code I found in asp's
ValidationGroup => WebResource.axd

```
function IsValidationGroupMatch(control, validationGroup) {
    if ((typeof(validationGroup) == "undefined") || (validationGroup == null)) {
        return true;
    }
    ...
}
```

Looks like if a validation group is not specified, it will validate all the validators.
How can I limit a validation group to itself?

Comment: Assign `detailsButton` to its own (nonempty) validation group, or set its `CausesValidation` property to `false`.

Comment: setup multiple groups; and on button clicks make sure you validate only the group that belongs with `this.Validate("costValGroup");` in `button_click` event and checking `if(this.IsValid)` immediately after that line; if at all you need to validate all groups in any button click, you can use `this.Validate();`